# Totally non-responsive to keyboard presses

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

This doesn't respond to pressing Enter -traces give no results.

Is there any way to do this that works?

This is just extra ridiculous writing to get past the ludicrous posting restrictions.

Yaddah.

boards.as

```
  package 
  {
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import mx.core.BitmapAsset;
    //import board;
    import flash.accessibility.AccessibilityImplementation;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.AntiAliasType; 
    import flash.utils.describeType;
    import flash.net.*;
    import Set;
    import StatusBox;
    import Statusx;
    import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.events.FocusEvent;
    import fl.managers.FocusManager;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class boxsprite extends Sprite  
    {     
        [Embed(source = "C:/Windows/Fonts/Verdana.ttf", fontName = "Verdana", fontWeight = "bold", advancedAntiAliasing = "true", mimeType = "application/x-font")] 
        public static const VERD:Class;
        [Embed(source="../lib/box.gif")]
         private var boxspriteClass:Class
         [Embed(source = "../lib/m2.gif")]
         private var m2:Class

         [Embed(source = "../lib/m3.gif")]
        private var m3:Class
         [Embed(source="../lib/m4.gif")]
        private var m4:Class
        [Embed(source = "../lib/m5.gif")]
        private var m5:Class
        [Embed(source = "../lib/m6.gif")]
        private var m6:Class

        [Embed(source = "../lib/m7.gif")]
        private var m7: Class
        [Embed(source="../lib/m8.gif")]
        private var m8: Class
        [Embed(source = "../lib/m9.gif")]
        private var m9: Class

        private var m22:Bitmap;
        private var m33:Bitmap;
        private var m44:Bitmap;
        private var m55:Bitmap;
        private var m66:Bitmap;
        private var m77:Bitmap;
        private var m88:Bitmap;
        private var m99:Bitmap;
        private var boxsprite2:Bitmap;

         internal var mode:uint=2;
            internal var displaytext:String;
            internal var setBox:Boolean = false;
            internal var onBoard:Array = [0];
            internal var playerRound:uint = 1;
            internal var round:uint = 1;
            internal var playernumber:uint; 
            internal var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();
            public function boxsprite():void
            {
                trace (mode);

            boxsprite2=new boxspriteClass() as Bitmap;
            this.addChild(boxsprite2); 
            m22 = new m2 as Bitmap;
            this.addChild(m22);

            m77= new m7 as Bitmap;

            this.addChild(m77);

            m66= new m6 as Bitmap;
            this.addChild(m66);

            m55= new m5 as Bitmap;
            this.addChild(m55);
            m44= new m4 as Bitmap;
            this.addChild(m44);
            m33= new m3 as Bitmap;
            this.addChild(m33);
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown2);
            }

            private function myKeyDown2(e2:KeyboardEvent):void
                {
                if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) 
                {
                trace("Enter pressed");
                    modeswitch();

                }


            else if (e2.keyCode ==Keyboard.H)
            {

            navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://wp.me/P3FUQl-n"));
            }
            //else if (e.Keycode == Keyboard.Q)
            function modeswitch():void
            {  trace(mode);
                switch(mode)
                {
                case 8: 

                {mode = 9;
                choosetext(); }

                case 9: 
                    {mode = 2;
                choosetext();
                }
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                {mode = 3; 
                choosetext();}
```

startBox.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, kill);

This code part in

Board.as- appears to work.

```
function kill (e2:KeyboardEvent):void

                {if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_1)
                   {removeChild(this.startBox);
                   startBox = null;
                   }
                 else if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_2)
                  {removeChild(this.startBox);
                   startBox = null;
                  }

                  else if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_3)
                  {removeChild(this.startBox);
                   startBox = null;
                  }
                  else if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_4)
                  {removeChild(this.startBox);
                   startBox = null;
                  }
                  else if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_5)
                  {removeChild(startBox);
                   startBox = null; }
                  else if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_6)

                { removeChild(this.board.startBox);
                   startBox = null;}
                 else if (e2.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
                {removeChild(startBox);
                 startBox = null;}
```

Maybe I've give up on keyboard for this part and use mouse events instead- in a previous structure I couldn't have done that as mouse was already occupied doing something but that should be freed up now.

By the way this isn't need on stage initialisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sprite will never receive any *KeyboardEvent*. You should add your event listeners directly to the stage. Of course, you have to obtain a link to the stage.

In your constructor delete

```
 this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown2);
```

And add the following:

```
    //Your constructor
...
if(stage)
    initKeyboardEvents();
else
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initKeyboardEvents)
//End of constructor
...
//New function
private function initKeyboardEvents(e:Event = null):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown2);
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work because I need to detect keystrokes in multiple classes- main,

Comment: This IS going to work because this is the way everyone does it. You can add several different listeners to your stage, they all are going to work as you want them to